# How to properly return data from an object through a command in another object

Tags: c++, class, object, linked-list, reference

I'm practicing coding, and created a "Buddy" program where an object can have a name and a buddy which holds the address of another object called "Buddies".

Here's my class:

```
    class Buddy {
public:
    Buddy() {
        name = "NoName";
    }
    Buddy(string newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
    void setName(string newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    void setBuddy(Buddy buddy2) {
        buddy = &buddy2;
    }
    string getBuddyName() {
        return buddy->getName();
    }
private:
    string name;
    Buddy *buddy = NULL;
};
```

In my main file, I'm assigning Buddy "a" a buddy named "b":

```
a.setBuddy(b);
b.setBuddy(a);
```

Then I want to cout the names of the individual objects through their assigned buddies, but I crash on this part. Here's the code:

```
cout << "A's Buddy: " << a.getBuddyName() << endl;
cout << "B's Buddy: " << b.getBuddyName() << endl;
```

Shouldn't this work? I am passing reference properly, I thought. Could you help me spot any bugs?

Comment: That isn't all of your test code. There's nothing that creates `a` and `b`. Please consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: You are not using references at all. And this `buddy = &buddy2;` sets the pointer  to point to a local copy which disappears when the function exits.

Comment: and if the member pointer `buddy` is invalid, `getBuddyName()` will dereference a null pointer

Comment: You really ought to use your constructors initialization list to initialize member variables rather than using the ctor body. The way you are doing it now is inefficient and also won't work for types that are not assignable (including `const` members of otherwise assignable types).

Comment: Interesting follow-up question: If `a` is buddies with `b`, shouldn't `b` be buddies with `a` by definition? Can the code be modified to take care of that automatically? (Without infinite recursion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these fixes:

```
void setBuddy(Buddy& buddy2) { // an actual reference, not a copy of the original
    buddy = &buddy2;
}
string getBuddyName() {
    return buddy ? buddy->getName() : string("");
}
```

The problem with `setBuddy` is that it stored the address of its parameter, a temporary object (copied when the function was called) that won't be valid after the function returns. And `getBuddyName` didn't check for a null `buddy` pointer before dereferencing it.